# Infinitely many prime ${2^{(n+1)}}(5^n)−1$ for some Natural number $n$.

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that there exist an infinite number of prime ${2^{(n+1)}}(5^n)−1$ for some Natural number $n$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
       n     &        {2^{(n+1)}}(5^n)−1       \\
\hline
      1     &         19     \\
      2     &         199     \\
      3     &         1999      \\
      5     &         199 999    \\
      .     &         .    \\
      .     &         .    \\
      .     &         .    \\
53     &         199 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 999 
      .     &         .    \\
      .     &         .    \\
      .     &         .    \\
\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I would be very surprised to see a proof that there are, or a proof that there are not.

Comment: It seems rather like asking for a proof regarding whether there are a finite number of Fermat primes. One can use probabilistic reasoning, or use computational techniques to check primality, but no proof seems in the cards. @AndréNicolas

Comment: These numbers are known to be prime for $n=1,2,3,5,7,26,27,53,147,236,248,386,401$, where $n$ is the number of $9$s. See https://oeis.org/A055558